# html5 canvas overlay cutout workaround in safari

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am trying to create an overlay that can highlight certain portions of the page. The best way I've figured out to do this is to use a canvas fit to the page, draw the shapes I need, and draw a rectangle using this trick:

```
ctx.rect(canvas.width, 0, 0 - canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

I'm not sure I can explain this well, so it might be best to look at the [jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/mattwbarry/ESt8t/5/) to get an idea of what I am trying to do.

This works perfectly in every browser except Safari. Is there any way to achieve this effect in Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try filling the whole canvas first, then use composite mode to knock out the shapes.

Example:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
ctx.fillRect(canvas.width, 0, 0 - canvas.width, canvas.height);

// next shape will punch hole in the draw rectangle above
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";  // make sure alpha is 100%

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(300, 60);
ctx.arc(300, 60, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.moveTo(500, 160);
ctx.arc(500, 160, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
drawEllipse(ctx, 103, 23, 100, 30)
drawEllipse(ctx, 503, 23, 100, 30)
ctx.fill();

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';  // reset comp. mode
```

**[Modifed fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/ESt8t/6/)**

Alpha (not the color) will determine how much visible the hole will be.

Hope this helps.